# Keeping track of dynamically generated form elements and passing them as POST variables

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page that retrieves records from 1 table in a database when a certain condition is met.

What I want to achieve is to provide the use to with an opportunity to update each record displayed using text boxes.

I am having trouble interpreting what logic to proceed with after the user hits the 'submit' button.

Normally, if I'm updating one record (or a static number of records), I will use the apporpriate amount of SQL statements.

Since the amount of records are dynamically generated, what is the best way to update all at once? How would I know which records were retrieved in the first place to update?

FOR EXAMPLE:

OK, We have a table with student ids (ID), names (SNAME), subjects (SUBJ), grade for each subject (GRADE) and general remarks (COMMENTS).

I want to retrieve information about all students that got an 'A', and write UNIQUE congratulatory remarks for each student (such as 'good job', or 'congratulations', or etc.)

I'd retrieve the records and lay them out on the page, with a text box next to each student record for the comments to be entered. Because I don't know how many text boxes to make, I give the text boxes dynamically generated names using the student ID. The user now enters unique comments for each student, and clicks on submit.

Now, how am I supposed to update these records with the values entered in each text box?

I wouldn't know which students were retrieved in the first place - how would I know what names to use? I'm trying to avoid having to execute the query again after submitting - but is there any other way?

Hope this question was not too confusing.

thanks

Comment: This is pretty vague, can you add some of your code and/or explain in a lot more detail?

Answer (score 2):

Further expanding earlier answers:
You need a loop (e.g. foreach) to display and save the textareas. If the names of the textareas include the students ID, you don't need to know the name, because the text is inserted to the database by the primary key (the students ID). You may name your form-elements as array, to iterate over them, for example (where the numbers are the IDs):

```
<textarea name="comment[2345234]"></textarea>
<textarea name="comment[8957485]"></textarea>
```

Read it out as described by @evan:

```
foreach((array)$_POST['comment'] as $studentId => $studentComment)
{
    var_dump($studentId, $studentComment);
}
```

And if you implement this whole thing as self-requesting form ([Affenformular](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affenformular) in german), you may also use just one single loop to save and output the textareas.

"I don't think you're understanding what I'm trying to ask." Maybe you don't understand the answers, even you stated it. You don't need a students name to save a database record. But if you really want to submit it, you may also use hidden inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Use `foreach()` to find the values you care about, put them in an array, and process the array.

Comment: Would you mind explaining how this would work? How would using 'foreach()' keep track of all the text boxes that are generated, and match up the data in the text boxes with the records that they are intended to update?

Comment: Because the JavaScript you use to generate those text boxes in the first place would name them appropriately.

Comment: I agree, but how would it keep the names after the 'submit' button is pressed

Comment: Huh? The `name` attribute of a form control is what's used for the POST parameter name.

Comment: I don't think you're understanding what I'm trying to ask. 

Let's say that 5 records are retrieved from the database, according to a certain condition. I'd use a while loop to list the contents of each record from mysql_fetch_assoc, and will place a text box next to each record with a dynamically generated name (using the primary key of each record). 

How do I let PHP know what records were retrieved after I press submit? Because I now need to update each record previously retrieved with values entered in each of the text boxes, how would I know which records to update?

Comment: The database records will have a specific PK. The PK will be added to a specific prefix to give a control name. The prefix will be looked for in the `foreach()` loop. The prefix will be stripped, and the PK will be known.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @Ignacio's answer to make it more easily understandable:

```
foreach($_POST as $name_of_input => $value_of_input)
{
    // do stuff - here is something so you can see the results after the submit
    echo "$name_of_input :: $value_of_input <br>";
}
```

Comment: I understand this part, but how do I let PHP know what $name_of_inputs to use? Remember that the items in the form are dynamically generated - I know how to retrieve the value of each input IF i know the name of the input. Is there any way to get a list of the NAMES of all variables passed over the _POST?

Comment: The names of the inputs are the keys in the $_POST.  If you do what I indicated and echo $name_of_input - it will output the name of the variables passed over the post.

Comment: You don't need to specify anything - $_POST will automatically have keys that match the names of the inputs that were submitted.